# How to build an image of a running container with ContainerD runtime

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, containerd

How can I build an image of a running container that uses ContainerD runtime?

Basically I have a Kubernetes Cluster in GCP and the Node uses containerD runtime and I want to generate the image of a running container.

Thank you

Comment: Usually things run in the other direction: you create an image and then run a container from it, using whatever container runtime is in your cluster.  Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?  Stack Overflow is exclusively about programming-related questions (also see the [help/on-topic]); is there any particular source code related to this question you could include?

Comment: Hi David Maze, thank you for the information. I understand how things works to create an image and run the container from it.

Let me try to explain what we want to do. I have a container that is running an image of the rundeck application. I accessed the application and made some changes within the application.

I would like to create an image of this container(like a snapshot) with the changes that I have made. If it was docker, I know how to do that but the problem here is that the runtime is containerD because the pod/container is running in a Node in GCP which uses containerD runtime.

Comment: Hello, 'm just suggesting a workaround, copy your Rundeck directory as all the changes you made will get reflected here. Now use this directory while building your Rundeck image and you can create a new deployment using this new image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish the desired task you will not be able to use CircleCI but instead you can use a tool called nerdctl, about which you can discover more on its official github page, https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl

You will have to install this tool on the node and then you can follow these steps to create an image from a container:
First, you would have to pull the image using the “docker pull” command if you don’t already have it (in this case you will have to remake the modifications), then you can start the container using “docker create”.
After the container is created and you have done the needed modification, you can do a commit using the “docker commit” command, then you will have to name your image according to the correct syntax that you have used when you first created the image in Container/Artifact Registry.
The last step is to upload the updated image to Container/Artifact Registry by using the “docker push” command.